# Android WifiManager failed when called RemoveNetwork()

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, wifimanager

I have implemented an app which will allow user to connect to a desired network.

If the SSID record is already remembered by phone. It will notify user to manually delete the SSID record.

Here is some sample code

```
temp = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < WiFi.ConfiguredNetworks.Count; i++)
{
    if (String.Compare(WiFi.ConfiguredNetworks[i].Ssid, ("\"" + SSID + "\"")) == 0)
    {
        temp = WiFi.ConfiguredNetworks[i].NetworkId;
        break;
    }
}

if(temp != -1) //This SSID is already remembered by phone
{
    bool success = WiFi.RemoveNetwork(temp)

    if(success == false)
    {
        //Call some function to notify user to manually remove the network
    }
}
```

Things happened at `//Call some function to notify user to manually remove the network`.

Sometimes the user goes to the wifi system page. They found out that there is no record of this SSID.

In my opinion, if `RemoveNetwork()` return failed, that means this SSID is already remembered by phone.

And it is not build by the current app.

Is that wrong?

Issue happened on device Nokia 8(Android 9).

Comment: What do you do in `//Call some function to notify user to manually remove the network`? There are many functions deprecated in API level 28. Please check the link below. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#removeNetwork(int)

Comment: The app navigate user to system network setting page.
But the question is. The code should not go to //Call some....
Because the RemoveNetwork() should not fail(in my opinion).

Comment: Have you check the SSID? The `RemoveNetwork()` should work on API 28. Please check the SSID. Maybe there is something wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs for [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#removeNetwork(int)) say:

```
Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always fail and return false.
```

If your API level is below 29 then you probably aren't passing a valid `NetworkId`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have the issue on Android 9 device.(Nokia 8).

Comment: What is the alternative of this API? removeNetwork() always returns false